# Unable to connect to internet after installing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows

I am using Windows 8.1, whenever I install SQL Server 2012 or 2014, I am unable to use my internet. I get an error

> There is no internet connection

When I uninstall SQL Server and perform system restore internet works fine. How to solve this issue? I want to install SQL Server.

Comment: Is the installer downloaded directly from Microsoft's?

Comment: This is really Weird.. first of all as @Martheen said check this installer, I never seen this before something related with SQL Server and Internet Connection..  the scenario that you have after install SQL Server, check your IP address etc..